# Python open url with urllib than get back the changed url of opened webpage

Tags: python, url, urllib2

I want to send some requests to Google maps. I open the url that is changed based on the request. And I want to get back the changed url.
An example:

```
import urllib, urllib2

my_address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043'
data = urllib.urlencode({'output':'csv', 'q':my_address})
req = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place?' + data)
res_0 = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res_0.geturl()
```

url to open (`res_0.geturl()`):

`'https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway+Mountain+View,+CA+94043/data=!4m2!2m1!4b1?dg=dbrw&newdg=1'`

And I want to get back the changed url, that is:

`'https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043,+USA/@37.4223371,-122.0866079,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808fba027820e5d9:0x60a90600ff6e7e6e!8m2!3d37.4223329!4d-122.0844192'`

I opened the `res_0` url in the browser manually and I get the above changed url.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .geturl() method inside urllib2

Example:

```
print res_0.geturl()
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed this from my example (I updated my question). So `res_0.geturl()` returns with "url to open". Or does this return the url that I want?